Help on IC identifying
Please help me on identifying the following chip.
Smd mark says "5MM 615".
Picture:


Addetto better picture.
It appeaers to me 5MM on the first line with 5M overlined.
615 on the bottom line with 6 and 5 underlined.

Can a more in-focus picture be taken, so that the marking code is readable? A better picture could may allow a manufacturer logo to be identified, to narrow down the possible devices.

The manufacturer is Ablic (formerly Seiko Instruments Inc. or SII) and the package is TMSOP-8. You can tell by the marking style with the concentric circle and under/over-lined characters.
Here is an example of the S-35770E01I-K8T2U which is a counter IC.

(Source: image.baidu.com)
And here is a S-25A640B0A-K8T2U3 which is an EEPROM.

(Source: tyro-teq.com)
Finding the exact IC in your picture will be difficult to impossible, because Ablic only specifies the markings in a few of their datasheets. All of the non-obsolete TMSOP-8 products are listed here: https://www.ablic.com/en/semicon/package/archive/tmsop-8-fm008-a/
Most of these are timers, battery ICs, EEPROMs or operational amplifiers. So if you can find out the function of the unknwon IC, you can at least narrow it down a bit.

I've asked directly to ABLIC field engineer. 5MM is not a recogjized marking....rally strange
